# Regular expression in index function

Tags: regex, perl, indexing, position

I am looking for occurrence of "CCGTCAATTC(A|C)TTT(A|G)AGT" in a text file.

`$text = 'CCGTCAATTC(A|C)TTT(A|G)AGT';
    if ($line=~/$text/){
    chomp($line);
    $pos=index($line,$text);
    }`

Searching is working, but I am not able to get the position of "text" in line.
It seems index does not accepts a regular expression as substring.

How can I make this work.
Thanks

Answer (score 14):

The `@-` array holds the offsets of the starting positions of the last successful match. The first element is the offset of the whole matching pattern, and subsequent elements are offsets of parenthesized subpatterns. So, if you know there was a match, you can get its offset as `$-[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `index` at all, just a regex. The portion of `$line` that comes before your regex match will be stored in `` $` `` (or `$PREMATCH` if you've chosen to use English;).  You can get the index of the match by checking the length of `` $` ``, and you can get the match itself from the `$&` (or `$MATCH`) variable:

```
$text = 'CCGTCAATTC(A|C)TTT(A|G)AGT';
if ($line =~ /$text/) {
    $pos = length($PREMATCH);
}
```

Assuming you want to get `$pos` to continue matching on the remaining part of `$line`, you can use the `$'` (or `$POSTMATCH`) variable to get the portion of `$line` that comes after the match.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html for detailed information on these special variables.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But once I capture the position then I am to capture the next 50 chars: `substr($line,$pos,50)`

Comment: You can match on the remaining part of $line the way you said -- is that approach undesirable for some reason?  You could also use the $' (or $POSTMATCH) variable to easily get the remaining part of $line.

Comment: Please see my amended answer; let me know if you're looking for something else.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Only thing is that this way I will loose the text. I mean text+x=50 words

Comment: Your worked, but as thought, I am missing the matching string.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can keep a variable that stores the length of the part of `$line` that was lost by adding `length($PREMATCH)` and `length($MATCH)` to it at every iteration.

Comment: You can get the match from the `$&` (or `$MATCH`) variable.  I have added this to my answer.

Comment: Okay, so I am going this way (using index etc..) so to know the location where the text was matched. I understood what you are saying, and giving some nice idea. May be I need to change the whole tactics now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, it seems like what you are after is matching the 50 characters directly following the match. So, a simple solution would be:

```
my ($match) = $line =~ /CCGTCAATTC[AC]TTT[AG]AGT(.{50})/;
```

As you see, `[AG]` is equivalent to `A|G`. If you wish to match multiple times, you can use an array `@matches`, and the `/g` global option on the regex. E.g.

```
my @matches = $line =~ /CCGTCAATTC[AC]TTT[AG]AGT(.{50})/g;
```

You can do this to keep the matching pattern:

```
my ($pattern, $match) = $line =~ /(CCGTCAATTC[AC]TTT[AG]AGT)(.{50})/g;
```

Or in a loop:

```
while ($line =~ /(CCGTCAATTC[AC]TTT[AG]AGT)(.{50})/g;) {
    my ($pattern, $match) = ($1, $2);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I need the matching chars so may be have to cheat and instead of 50 put 38

Comment: Wouldn't your question have been a whole lot simpler to answer if you'd said from the start what you wanted? =) Well, assuming you do know how many characters you want to capture, I think you can work out how to fix it.

Comment: This also gave me another idea, so that TLP

Comment: Yes, could have been bit more clear for the next few steps I was trying to do... Will be careful for next time

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($line =~ /(CCGTCAATTC[AC]TTT[AG]AGT)(.{50})/g;) {
```

I like it, but no `;` in `while`.

I had hard times to search for the reason of errors. T_T.